# Process memory limit and address space for UNIX and Linux and Windows

Tags: memory, memory-management, process, operating-system

what is the maximum amount of memory for a single process in UNIX and Linux and windows? how to calculate that? How much user address space and kernel address space for 4 GB of RAM?

Answer (score 7):

`How much user address space and kernel address space for 4 GB of RAM?`

The address space of a process is divided into two parts,

**User space**: On standard 32 bit x86_64 architecture,the maximum addressable memory is `4GB`, out of which addresses from `0x00000000` to `0xbfffffff` = `(3GB)` meant for code, data segments. This region can be addressed when user process executing either in user or kernel mode.

**Kernel space**: Similarly, addresses from `0xc0000000` to `0xffffffff` = `(1GB)` are meant for virtual address space of the kernel and can only addressed when the process executes in kernel mode.

This particular address space split on `x86` is determined by the value of `PAGE_OFFSET`. Referring to Linux `3.11.1v` [page_32_types.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.11.1/arch/x86/include/asm/page_32_types.h#L6) and [page_64_types.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.11.1/arch/x86/include/asm/page_64_types.h#L27), page offset is defined as below,

`#define __PAGE_OFFSET           _AC(CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET, UL)`

Where [Kconfig](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.11.1/arch/x86/Kconfig#L1200) defines a default value of `default 0xC0000000` also with other address split options available.

Similarly for 64 bit,

`#define __PAGE_OFFSET           _AC(0xffff880000000000, UL)`.

On 64 bit architecture `3G`/`1G` split doesn't hold anymore due to huge address space. As per the source latest Linux version has given above offset as offset.

When I see my 64 bit x86_64 architecture, a 32 bit process can have entire `4GB` of user address space and kernel will hold address range above `4GB`. Interestingly on modern 64 bit x86_64 CPU's not all address lines are enabled(or the address bus is not large enough) to provide us `2^64` = `16 exabytes` of virtual address space. Perhaps `AMD64`/`x86` architectures has `48`/`42` lower bits enabled respectively resulting to `2^48` = `256TB` / `2^42`= `4TB` of address space. Now this definitely improves performance with large amount of RAM, at the same time question arises how it is efficiently managed with the OS limitations.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux there's a way to find out the limit of address space you can have.
Using the `rlimit` structure.

```
struct rlimit {
    rlim_t cur;    //current limit
    rlim_t max;    //ceiling for cur.
}
```

`rlim_t` is a `unsigned long` type.

and you can have something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

//Bytes To GigaBytes
static inline unsigned long btogb(unsigned long bytes) {
    return bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
}

//Bytes To ExaBytes
static inline double btoeb(double bytes) {
    return bytes / (1024.00 * 1024.00 * 1024.00 * 1024.00 * 1024.00 * 1024.00);
}

int main() {

    printf("\n");

    struct rlimit rlim_addr_space;
    rlim_t addr_space;

    /*
    * Here we call to getrlimit(), with RLIMIT_AS (Address Space) and
    * a pointer to our instance of rlimit struct.
    */
    int retval = getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &rlim_addr_space);
    // Get limit returns 0 if succeded, let's check that.
    if(!retval) {
        addr_space = rlim_addr_space.rlim_cur;
        fprintf(stdout, "Current address_space: %lu Bytes, or %lu GB, or %f EB\n", addr_space, btogb(addr_space), btoeb((double)addr_space));
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Coundn\'t get address space current limit.");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I ran this on my computer and... prrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr tsk!

**Output:** `Current address_space: 18446744073709551615 Bytes, or 17179869183 GB, or 16.000000 EB`

I have 16 ExaBytes of max address space available on my Linux x86_64.

Here's [getrlimit()'s definition](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)
it also lists the other constants you can pass to `getrlimits()` and introduces `getrlimit()`s sister `setrlimit()`. There is when the `max` member of `rlimit` becomes really important, you should always check you don't exceed this value so the kernel don't punch your face, drink your coffee and steal your papers.

PD: please excuse my sorry excuse of a drum roll ^_^

Answer (score 1):

On Linux systems, see [man ulimit](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ulimit/)

(UPDATED)

It says:

> The ulimit builtin is used to set the resource usage limits of the
>   shell and any processes spawned by it. If a new limit value is
>   omitted, the current value of the limit of the resource is printed.

*ulimit -a* prints out all current values with switch options, other switches, e.g. *ulimit -n* prints out no. of max. open files.

Unfortunatelly, "max memory size" tells "unlimited", which means that it is not limited by system administrator.

You can view the memory size by

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

Which results something like:

```
MemTotal:        4048744 kB
MemFree:          465504 kB
Buffers:          316192 kB
Cached:          1306740 kB
SwapCached:          508 kB
Active:          1744884 kB
(...)
```

So, if *ulimit* says "unlimited", the MemFree is all yours. Almost.

Don't forget that *malloc()* (and *new* operator, which calls *malloc()*) is a STDLIB function, so if you call *malloc(100)* 10 times, [there will be lot of "slack"](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~huangj/cs360/360/notes/Malloc1/lecture.html), follow link to learn why.